# localhost WP login not working

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

So I changed my root user name's password and ever since I made this change my user that i have created for my WP login once entered gives the following reply:

ERROR: The password you entered for the username test is incorrect. Lost your password?

It clearly shows my username and password setup in my database's wp_users. So I really do not understand what is going on here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you changed password in md5 format ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer screenshot[image]

md5 the change password.....

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Do you know how it changed though? very curious. :)

Answer (score 2):

[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dVC.png)

Please see the image. while you are updating password from phpmyadmin select md5 and then you can use plain password